# Toad is working properly but not cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have installed Oracle Client 12.2.0 on my desktop and my laptop. When I am using TOAD, everything is working fine in both of them. However, when using cx_Oracle in Jupyter Notebook with my desktop, I get this error: "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library". Interestingly, I do not get this error on my laptop at all. On both of them, my python is 64-bit while the oracle client is 32-bit.

I am wondering why I am getting this error in just one of them.
I almost used all the solutions in different posts but none of them worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for my problem:

1. Download 64-bit version of oracle instantClient from: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html
2. Copy the dll files in the instantclient directory to the python directory, as shown below

[image]

[image]

That is it!

Answer (score 0):

If Python is 64-bit it will only run with a 64-bit Oracle Client.  You haven't given useful info such as the operating system and versions so I can only give generic info either:

- make sure a 64-bit Oracle Client is in your library search path (PATH on Windows, LD_LIBRARY_PATH or via ldconfig on Linux) *before* starting Juptyer
- or on Windows and macOS make use of cx_Oracle 8's [`init_oracle_client()`](http://If%20Python%20is%2064-bit%20it%20will%20only%20run%20with%20a%2064-bit%20Oracle%20Client.%20%20You%20haven%27t%20given%20useful%20info%20such%20as%20the%20operating%20system%20and%20versions%20so%20I%20can%20only%20give%20generic%20info:%20either%20(i)%20make%20sure%20the%2064-bit%20Oracle%20Client%20is%20in%20your%20library%20search%20path%20(PATH%20on%20Windows,%20LD_LIBRARY_PATH%20or%20via%20ldconfig%20on%20Linux)%20_before_%20starting%20Juptyer%20(ii)%20or%20on%20Windows%20and%20macOS%20make%20use%20of%20cx_Oracle%208%27s%20%60init_oracle_client()%60%20function.) function.